# Can I start a module graph in Webpack from an HTML file?

Tags: webpack

I'd like Webpack to start building the module graph from my index.html file, building scripts, css, etc based on what I have in `<script>`, `<link>`, etc. Is there a way to achieve this?

Also, why isn't this the default mode of operation? Do I maybe misunderstand something about the semantics of how Webpack works?

Answer (score 2):

By default, webpack packs everything into a single JS file. Without extra work (ExtractTextPlugin, CommonChunksPlugin, etc.), you're not going to see the modules built out separately.

Specific to including assets referenced in the index.html into the compiled JS, use the [HTML Loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader).